# Where my log messages?

Tags: android, logging

I have source file like this:

```
...
import android.util.Log;
...
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    public static Activity activity = null;
    private static final String TAG = "WorldDetermine";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    public final int cameraId = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("myTag", "onCreate started!");
    Log.v("blah", "blah blah");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); ...
```

and trying to get log messages by `logcat`. Something like this:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 logcat myTag:D blah:v *:S
```

but have only blank output(grep isn't find this too). My project compiled by `ant debug` properly but I have problem on last step(Can the problem be caused indirectly by this?):

```
debug:

BUILD FAILED
/home/psct/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:887: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/psct/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:342: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/psct/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:334: Problem: failed to create task or type propertyfile
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant-core/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem


Total time: 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Start ddms file in /android-sdk/tools folder, and you'll see verbose output for selected device. Logs will be in output. No need for using console :)

Comment: Well in output log you can see any existing errors in project (besides your own logs). And you can search them via tag, pid, app, text.. no need for console.
Anyway you have problem with importing apache library in project. Thats why no logs print out. Have you checked Project properties/Java_Build_Path. Try "Add External JAR" and select that apache jar file you have.

"Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists..it is a configuration problem"

Comment: and what the file is? Are you know?

Comment: It is in ant-nodeps package that need to install to load . Ok, resolved. p.s. ddms is sucks, it starts time around 5 sec, wtf...

Comment: Ok, but sooner or later you'll end up with ddms.. (especially if you dont have real android device to develop apps). Its starts normaly on my comp.
Glad i helped a little ;).

Comment: Yours comments contain answer but Answer isn't, if you edit yours answer I click "accept it".